# How to use Checkstyle plugin in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I am interested to know how to use CheckStyle.

I am doing static code analysis in Hudson, as first part, I installed Static Analyser and CheckStyle plugins in Hudson. But I am not able to find out how to use it in official Hudson checkstyple page also.

official page : http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Checkstyle+Plugin

If you can show me a step by step procedure, that is more helpful to me.

Comment: You need to run CheckStyle as part of your build job; Hudson just displays the results from your build.  What build framework (Ant, Maven, Gradle etc.) are you using ?

Comment: @gareth_bowles I think you should post this commment as reply. Because it is a very good answer. People thougt hudson's checkstyle plugin analyse and generate results but actually it just displays the results

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as an answer per request:

You need to run CheckStyle as part of your build job; Hudson just displays the results from your build. Here is documentation for the [Ant task](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/anttask.html) and the [Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/).

Comment: Can you please share the ant/maven example for this @gareth_bowles?

Answer (score 0):

In the Hudson build job configuration screen you should find a checkbox that turns on Checkstyle. You don't need to change your Maven scripts.  I don't know if Ant scripts would need adjustment as we always use Maven.